# Car registration similarity

Tags: combinatorics, probability

In my city, car registration plates contain 3 numbers (0 to 9) and 3 letters (A to Z). Today I've noticed that my neighbour's car has the same registration as my car except for one character. Should I be surprised by this? In other words, what is the probability of this happening for two randomly chosen cars in my city?

Comment: This seems like a mathematics question sorry I am voting to close it.

Comment: This is unsolvable without the assumption of randomness, which isn't stated. (If plates are issued sequentially, a dealership registering 6 cars at the same time will cause a clump of "neighbouring" plates getting sold in the same geographical area.)

Answer (score 2):

[Given all the standard assumptions, that is]

The neighbour's car's number should be differing from yours in exactly one of three symbols. Thus, there are (26-1)*3 = 75 people, who are qualified for being your neighbours.

Given that all of we can count 1000*26*26*26 = 17576000 possible car plates, and exclude yours, maybe (Given, we are talking two *different* cars). In reality, the amount of cars will probably be less, and the occasion will be more probable.

Nevertheless, this gives us 75/17575999 = 0,00000426718 = 0,000426718%. You could bet, like, a cent against 2000 dollars that this will happen, and any mathematic making dumb assumptions would take the bet.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is a bit flawed:
You make an observation and then wonder if you should be surprised. For that, the real question is: "What is the chance that I saw a pattern as remarkable as 1 differing letter."

That chance is hard to tell but I think it will at least include many other patterns, like the chance of 1 number differing, all number being 1 higher etc.

So it depends on your pattern recognition skill, but I would say if the the registration numbers would be random, the chance is extremely low, even if it becomes 100 or 1000 times Thomas' result in the other answer.